# Show carbon username in WSO2 Identity Server 5.2 with OpenID

Tags: wso2, openid, jwt, wso2-identity-server

I can get id_token from WSO2 5.2 by hitting
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/token

The id_token can be customized by mapping local claim to OIDC claim in open id.

For instance, I can add role in the JWT token from WSO2. However, I can't get WSO2 user shows up in the token.

```
{
  "at_hash": "VFjcb6kEgMrXIemmg7AAMQ",
  "sub": "kramercecret",
  "iss": "https://a2d92f278368:9443/oauth2/token",
  "preferred_username": "Pikachu Jigglpuff",
  "given_name": "Pikachu Jigglpuff",
  "aud": [
    "3j8Bf3bx_mdLagZgTjaZUeDHjAoa"
  ],
  "azp": "3j8Bf3bx_mdLagZgTjaZUeDHjAoa",
  "auth_time": 1467078553,
  "scope": [
    "Internal/everyone",
    "Approver"
  ],
  "name": "Pikachu Jigglpuff",
  "exp": 1467082172,
  "iat": 1467078572,
  "email": "pikachu.jigglypuff@yahoo.com"
}
```

Has anyone done this before?

The purpose of this is to access the username in the ID_Token and let the spring security to decode the JWT token, then store the username in the database.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you want the username with the tenant domain (eg: admin@carbon.super) or the tenant aware username (eg: admin)

Comment: Identity Server sends username in the sub claim. If you try to send the username claim as a separate claim, it may not work because username claim and sub claim are mapped to the same attribute in the user store.